# Setting Puppet extension on Azure VM

Tags: azure, puppet

I am trying to add Puppet agent to an already existing Azure VM via Azure Powershell 1.0. The official documentation refers to use of the following:

```
Parameter Set: SetPuppetExtension
Set-AzureVMPuppetExtension [-PuppetMasterServer] <String> [[-Version] <String> ] [[-Disable]] [[-ReferenceName] <String> ] -VM <IPersistentVM> [ <CommonParameters>]
```

I am trying to get -VM parameter out of Azure via get-AzureRmVm (which BTW returns details of the VM), but set-AzureVMPuppetExtension is not having it:

```
Set-AzureVMPuppetExtension : Cannot bind parameter 'VM'. Cannot convert the "$VM" value of type "System.String" to type 
"Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.Model.IPersistentVM".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is that `Set-AzureVMPuppetExtension` expects the output from `Get-AzureVM` not `Get-AzureRmVm`

This is the old service model, classic VMs, way of doing things. It has gotten considerably more complex now.

Firstly to find the extension you want you need to use

```
Get-AzureRmVMImagePublisher -Location $location
```

you can then use

```
 Get-AzureRmVMExtensionImageType -PublisherName puppetlabs -Location $location
```

which will give you the details you need to use with

```
Set-AzureRmVMExtension
```

Comment: This actually worked (kind of): 'Set-AzureRmVMExtension -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -VMName <VMName> -Name PuppetEnterpriseAgent -Publisher PuppetLabs -ExtensionType PuppetEnterpriseAgent -location $location -TypeHandlerVersion "3.8"'